# Statistics and Cardinality Estimation - Why am I seeing this result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I came across this little issue when trying to solve a more complex problem and have gotten to the end of my rope with trying to figure the optimizer out. So, let's say I have a table called `MyTable' that can be defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
GroupClosuresID int identity(1,1) not null, 
SiteID int not null, 
DeleteDateTime datetime null
, CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY (GroupClosuresID, SiteID))
```

This table has 286,685 rows in it and running `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS('MyTable','PK_MyTable')` will yield:

```
Name                                                                                                                             Updated              Rows                 Rows Sampled         Steps  Density       Average key length String Index Filter Expression                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Unfiltered Rows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------ ------------- ------------------ ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
PK_MyTable                                                                                                                       Aug 10 2011  1:00PM  286685               286685               18     0.931986      8                  NO           NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             286685

(1 row(s) affected)

All density   Average Length Columns
------------- -------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3.743145E-06  4              GroupClosuresID
3.488149E-06  8              GroupClosuresID, SiteID

(2 row(s) affected)

RANGE_HI_KEY RANGE_ROWS    EQ_ROWS       DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS  AVG_RANGE_ROWS
------------ ------------- ------------- -------------------- --------------
1            0             8             0                    1
129          1002          7             127                  7.889764
242          826           6             112                  7.375
531          2010          6             288                  6.979167
717          1108          5             185                  5.989189
889          822           4             171                  4.807017
1401         2044          4             511                  4
1763         1101          3             361                  3.049861
14207        24780         1             12443                1.991481
81759        67071         1             67071                1
114457       31743         1             31743                1
117209       2047          1             2047                 1
179109       61439         1             61439                1
181169       1535          1             1535                 1
229410       47615         1             47615                1
235846       2047          1             2047                 1
275456       39442         1             39442                1
275457       0             1             0                    1
```

Now I run a query on this table with no additional indexes or statistics having been created.

```
SELECT GroupClosuresID FROM MyTable WHERE SiteID = 1397 AND DeleteDateTime IS NULL
```

Two new statistics objects now appear, one for the `SiteID` column and the other for `DeleteDateTime` column. Here they are respectively (Note: Some non-relevant information has been excluded):

```
Name                                                                                                                             Updated              Rows                 Rows Sampled         Steps  Density       Average key length String Index Filter Expression                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Unfiltered Rows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------ ------------- ------------------ ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
_WA_Sys_00000002_7B0C223C                                                                                                        Aug 10 2011  1:15PM  286685               216605               200    0.03384706    4                  NO           NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             286685

(1 row(s) affected)

All density   Average Length Columns
------------- -------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.0007380074  4              SiteID

(1 row(s) affected)

RANGE_HI_KEY RANGE_ROWS    EQ_ROWS       DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS  AVG_RANGE_ROWS
------------ ------------- ------------- -------------------- --------------
.
.
.
1397         59.42782      16005.02      5                    11.83174
.
.
.



Name                                                                                                                             Updated              Rows                 Rows Sampled         Steps  Density       Average key length String Index Filter Expression                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Unfiltered Rows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------ ------------- ------------------ ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
_WA_Sys_00000006_7B0C223C                                                                                                        Aug 10 2011  1:15PM  286685               216605               201    0.7447883     0.8335911          NO           NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             286685

(1 row(s) affected)

All density   Average Length Columns
------------- -------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.0001065871  0.8335911      DeleteDateTime

(1 row(s) affected)

RANGE_HI_KEY            RANGE_ROWS    EQ_ROWS       DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS  AVG_RANGE_ROWS
----------------------- ------------- ------------- -------------------- --------------
NULL                    0             255827        0                    1
.
.
.
```

The execution plan generated for the query I ran above gives me no surprises. It consists of a simple Clustered Index Scan with **14282.3** estimated rows and 15676 actual rows. From what I've learned about statistics and cost estimation, using the two histograms above we can multiply the selectivity of SiteID (16005.02 / 286685) times the selectivity of DeleteDateTime (255827 / 286685) to get a composite selectivity of 0.0498187307480119. Multiplying that times the total number of rows (286685) gives us the exact same thing the optimizer did: **14282.3**.

But here is where I get confused. I create an index with `CREATE INDEX IX_MyTable ON Mytable (SiteID, DeleteDateTime)` which creates its own statistics object:

```
Name                                                                                                                             Updated              Rows                 Rows Sampled         Steps  Density       Average key length String Index Filter Expression                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                Unfiltered Rows
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------ ------------- ------------------ ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
IX_MyTable                                                                                                                       Aug 10 2011  1:41PM  286685               286685               200    0.02749305    8.822645           NO    NULL                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                             286685

(1 row(s) affected)

All density   Average Length Columns
------------- -------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0.0007107321  4              SiteID
7.42611E-05   4.822645       SiteID, DeleteDateTime
3.488149E-06  8.822645       SiteID, DeleteDateTime, GroupClosuresID

(3 row(s) affected)

RANGE_HI_KEY RANGE_ROWS    EQ_ROWS       DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS  AVG_RANGE_ROWS
------------ ------------- ------------- -------------------- --------------
.
.
.
1397         504           15686         12                   42
.
.
.
```

When I run the same query as before (`SELECT GroupClosuresID FROM MyTable WHERE SiteID = 1397 AND DeleteDateTime IS NULL`) I still get 15676 rows returned, **but my estimated row count is now 181.82**.

I've tried manipulating numbers to try and figure out where this estimation is coming from but I just can't get it. I have to assume it is related to the density values for IX_MyTable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

EDIT: Here is the execution plan for that last query execution.
[image: Last run]

Comment: How many executions were there on the operator with the row estimate of 181.82?

Comment: Also please show additional node values for the new index.

Comment: 1 execution. I added a screen shot as well. When you say additional node values you mean the other histogram values?

Comment: The values are now there

Comment: OK, if I had to guess it would be related to the distribution of the second key in the index.  How many values are there for that, do you know?

Comment: The second key being 1007, there are three values. All of which have a NULL DeleteDateTime.

Comment: got it, check the answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one took some digging!

It's a product of:

- `NULL` density in your date field (from your first set of stats `255827/286685 = .892363`
- ...times the density of the first field (`siteid`) in your new index: `0.0007107321`

The  formula is:

```
.00071017321 * 286685 = 203.7562 
-- est. rows with your value in siteid based on even distribution of values

255827 / 286685 = 0.892363
-- Probability of a NULL across all rows

203.7562 * 0.892363 = 181.8245
```

I'm guessing that since the row count in this instance doesn't actually affect anything, the optimizer took the easiest route and just multiplied the probabilities together.

Comment: You, sir, are a scholar and a gentleman. Thank you! By the way, how did you figure this out? It seemed to me that the optimizer would still be able to take advantage of the 15686 value but I guess not.

Comment: I put it into a spreadsheet, put in all the stats we knew, and played around with it.  It made a lot of sense once I found the answer, but basically I just multiplied rowcounts by densities and frequencies

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to write about it, but JNK was first.

Basically hash function calculates results now for two columns. And hash function result for SiteID = 1397 AND DeleteDateTime IS NULL matches approx 181 rows.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Hash_function